# Can't use Qt5Compat.GraphicalEffects as it requires a version

Tags: pyqt, qml, pyside, qt6, pyqt6

I am using Qt Creator 7.0.0 Based on Qt 6.2.3.

In order to use GraphicalEffects we have to use following method described:
https://doc.qt.io/qt-6.2/qtgraphicaleffects5-index.html

Now, if I apply this method I can easily access all its functionalities and write qml file.
When the qml file is ran it produces "Library import requires a version" error.

Comment: If you are asked for a version you are most likely using PyQt5, please provide a [mre]

Comment: It doesn't matter what version of Qt Creator you're using. What matters is the "kit" you've configured your project with.

Comment: Have you included the module in your project file? You'll need to add something like `QT += qt5compat`

Comment: For minimal reproducible example just import Qt5compat.GraphicalEffects in .qml file and try to run the application. However, my kit is Desktop Qt 6.2.4 MinGW 64-bit.